# high RAM usage when using mobileCore Ad Network

Tags: android, libgdx, ads, ram

Has anyone else used mobileCore for OfferWall ads in their android app?

I have recently switched from google interstitial ads to mobileCore interstitials. But I have noticed the RAM usage in the app jumped an extra 100MB since the switch. Has anyone else experienced this? Maybe I did something wrong in my code.

I initialized it in my onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = this;

    //create the mobileCore ads
    MobileCore.init(mActivity, MOBILE_CORE_HASH, LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, AD_UNITS.OFFERWALL, AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ);
```

then I called it here

```
public void showMobileCoreOfferWall(){
    if(MobileCore.isOfferwallReady()){
        MobileCore.showOfferWall(mActivity, null, true);
    } else {
        MobileCore.showOfferWall(mActivity, null, true);
        MobileCore.refreshOffers();
    }
}

public void showMobileCoreStickee(boolean show){
    if(show){
        if(MobileCore.isStickeeReady()){
            MobileCore.showStickee(mActivity);
        } else {
            MobileCore.showStickee(mActivity);
            MobileCore.refreshOffers();
        }
    } else {
        if(MobileCore.isStickeeShowing()){
            MobileCore.hideStickee();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What types of high RAM useage you are talking about as I have also used the same but not getting problem like yours

Comment: When my app is running, it was usually around 120MB when viewing the active applications screen on my Galaxy S4: RAM: 120MB, CPU 0.0%. This was back when I was using google ads. When I switch it to mobileCore and view the active applications, app is now 220MB, CPU 0.0% or more.

Comment: It seems I think there is not problem with mobilecore, do rechecking of your code once again